# Can not install Workflow Manager to work with SharePoint Server 2013 farm

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, workflow, sharepoint-server, workflow-manager

I installed SP Server 2013 and Workflow Manager in one server. When I configure Workflow Manager to work with SharePoint Server 2013 farm (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj658588), I am encountering this error:
[image]

Site is existing.
Help me plz

Answer (score 0):

Most probably a typo? There is a "/" between your host name and the port of your WorkflowHostUri

Try this:

```
Register-SPWorkflowService –SPSite "http://101ducna4" –WorkflowHostUri "http://101ducna4:12291" –AllowOAuthHttp
```

Comment: I'm try by your command code but get the same error. it can not find SPSite url